# Can't click the allow button in Flash

Tags: flash

Every time I want to enable my webcam or microphone in my browser, the regular flash screen pops up and I need click allow or deny.

However I can not click allow or deny, it is not responding to my clicks.

Does anyone know a fix ?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003724/cant-click-allow-button-in-flash-on-firefox

Comment: Almost 4 years, and the same problem persists... sad!

Comment: [I just created bugreport](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4137928), so **everyone** may vote for that to be fixed.

Answer (score 35):

access 
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html

1. select link
2. click never ask again

Comment: This has no effect.

Comment: The above worked for me. You can also run flash-player-properties on Dash by typing in "Adobe".  Then go to the website you want to allow Cam/Mic access. Set it to Allow. Make sure you click on the Camera & Mic Access column of the site, and not the name of the website so the drop-down options will show  because the layout looks just like a text list that's unclickable.

Comment: Clicking `never ask again` sets the available storage to 0. 
I don't know why it's called `never ask again` it's more like `disable storage`.

Comment: It worked in Firefox 20.0, but not in Chromium 25.0. Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Those who's having trouble. There's 7 tabs that you can choose under the settings. So: choose "Website Privacy Settings" which is the third from the right (picture of an eye on a monitor). Choose which web that you want to allow in the list and select "Always Allow". It works when i'm trying to let tunerr.com to access my microphone.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to restart the browser.

Comment: Delete all the websites it knows about, then visit the website you are interested in. Go back to the settings manager, select the relevant website and allow just that website access to whatever it wants, and select the "Never ask again" option. Then reload the site and it should all be fine.

Comment: +1 for a helpful workaround, but it would be nice to have a way to actually click the box when it comes up.

Comment: Yes, looks like Ubuntu (or Linux?) is made of workarounds, rarely the real solution...

Comment: For rosettastone, I had to add it to the `Global Securities Panel` (third from the left).

Answer (score 7):

When you surf to [Settings Manager - Website Privacy Settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html), which will bring you to the tab with the monitor with the eye on, you need to do the following:

1. Find the site in the list and click on it..
2. Click on **Always allow**.
3. Go back to the site and refresh the page, the dialog will pop up again but this time you are able to click on the **Allow** button.

Tried and got it to work this way.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, this doesn't help b/c it doesn't allow me to click on allow in the given link

Comment: Had the same issue as @tofu_bacon, magically fixed it by setting global storage configuration to 10MB then deleting all from the per site storage configuration

Answer (score 3):

I think this is related to a problem others are having about not being able to interact with the flash player settings window, sometimes not at all and sometimes only in fullscreen.

For me, the culprit was Adblock Plus in both Chromium and Firefox. When wanting to work with a YouTube video, I disabled Adblock Plus on youtube.com, and so forth.

Comment: it's the `flashblock` addon. if you add both the domain where the embed tag is in (the one in your address bar while viewing the flash) and the domain that the option screen is asking access for, it will work. but you still have the bug where you can't interact with the settings screen, but now the camera access will be allowed always. not exactly a fix...

Comment: For me, it was necessary to uncheck ABP's "Show tabs on Flash and Java" option.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I was having the exact same problem until I wrote on the adress bar **chrome://plugins** and then I clicked in more details located at the top right and I disabled the adobe flash player plugin and enabled the **PepperFlash** one but I'm using google chrome so this will only work for google chrome users.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally I found another workaround: I clicked inside the flash window, then managed to choose the settings with the «Tab» button, then pressed enter.

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox, go to Tools, go to Addons. Click on that list Adobe Flash, click dropdown menu and change Always ask to Always start. Now when you on Omegle or other flash based webcam chat etc., your cam WILL IMMEDIATELY open, without asking allow/no. If you don't want that "black screen" see you, just block web cam at start until you are sure you want to share cam to other person. You can also block cam accessa in omegle when needed by a button in camera area.