# Flash player settings dialog unclickable

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash : can't click the allow button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74332/flash-cant-click-the-allow-button)

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, firefox 8, flash player 11 installed by software-center. I found i can't click the settings dialog of flash player. I click on the button but nothing happens.

It's a little similar with http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=978212 , however i'm a newbie and don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me and give a detail?